# Build Release: Version code not found in manifest

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, apk

I generated a project using React-Native and followed the [official RN guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) to publish to Play Store.

When I get to the buildRelease step. This outputs the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':java:packageReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Version code not found in manifest.

When I use assembleRelease however, the build creates an apk without any issues. What am I missing?

The default config under app/build.gradle is configured as such:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.appname"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i had to disable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
```